# Removing last character from a column

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm new to google sheets/excel. I wish to remove the last character from a column filled with words. Is there any slicing formula to do it?

Comment: Please, either Excel **or** Google-Sheets. The two are actually quite different despite looking alike. Then, also include your own attempt at solving your own issue. Let us know what isn't working about it. It's best to show sample data with that.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

To remove last char from a string, you can use LEFT combined with LEN in Excel.

My formula in B1 is `=LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-1)`

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(""&A1:A; ".$"; ))
```

[image]